# Postgresql : Check if the last number is the highest

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, max

I have **large database** and one field should be an incremental number, but it sometimes resets and I must detect them (the bold rows)

```
Table 1:
Shop    #Sell       DATE
EC1         56          1/10/2015
EC1         57          2/10/2015
**EC1           11          3/10/2015
EC1         12          4/10/2015**
AS2         20          1/10/2015
AS2         21          2/10/2015
AS2         22          3/10/2015
AS2         23          4/10/2015
```

To solve this problem I thought to find the highest number of each SHOP and check if it is the number with the highest DATE. Do you know another easier way to do it?

My concern is that it can be a problem to do the way I am thinking since I have a large database.

Do you know how I can do the query I am thinking of or do you have any others ideas?

Comment: So what's the expected result?

Comment: You did not define what you want *exactly*. I also doubt you are running two RDBMS in parallel, and with unknown version number and table definition (with exact data types and constraints). And we generally like to see what you have tried, even if it's not working.

Comment: I want to detect those shops (the id of the shop is enough). I wanted some functions as they provide me below, however I can't use them, because the server I am currently using doesnt support it. I have to use basic functions such as MAX or MIN, I guess I have to do some sort of subquery.

Comment: @PedroPereira . . . What version of Postgres are you using?  You should tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The query you have in mind will give you all `Shop` values having a discontinuity in `Sell` number.

If you want to get the *offending* record you can use the following query:

```
SELECT Shop, Sell, DATE
FROM (
 SELECT Shop, Sell, DATE,
        LAG(Sell) OVER (PARTITION BY Shop ORDER BY DATE) AS prevSell
 FROM Shops ) t
 WHERE Sell < prevSell
ORDER BY DATE 
LIMIT 1
```

The above query will return the *first* discontinuity found within each `Shop` partition.

**Output:**

```
Shop    Sell    DATE
---------------------
EC1     11      2015-03-10
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b327/1)

**EDIT:**

In case you cannot use windowed function and you only want the id of the shop having the discontinuity, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT s.Shop
FROM Shops AS s
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Shop, MAX(Sell) AS Sell, MAX(DATE) AS DATE
   FROM Shops
   GROUP BY Shop ) t 
ON s.Shop = t.Shop AND s.DATE = t.DATE
WHERE t.Sell <> s.Sell
```

The above will work provided that you have unique `DATE` values per `Shop`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answear I am pretty sure I could get what I wanted with you query, however the server, as I mentioned above, doesn't support those functions. I have to use basics functions to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is the type of query you want:

```
select s.*
from (select shop, max(sell) as maxsell, 
             first_value(sell) over (partition by shop order by date desc) as lastsell
      from shops s
      group by shop
     ) s
where maxsell <> lastsell;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answear I am pretty sure I could get what I wanted with you query, however the server, as I mentioned above, doesn't support those functions. I have to use basics functions to get what I want.

Comment: This is not allowed. Even if you put the `first_value(..) over (..)` in `having` clause instead of `lastsell`, you'll get an error: `ERROR:  window functions are not allowed in HAVING`